# More Moderators on SF?

Tags: discussion, moderators, serverfault

I noticed that, while we have (at this point in time, 2009-09-02) [4 people who qualify for moderator status on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/users), only one has been granted the "diamond".  Are we going to have more moderators in the near future, or will poor [Splattne](https://serverfault.com/users/45/splattne) be left to fend for himself?  Just curious.

Edit:

I'm talking about **non-employees**, folks.  Read the question *again* - please.

Re-Edit:

So it seems there's confusion on two fronts - moderators are not necessarily "employees", but at the same time, the verbage used to describe their access isn't exactly clear either.

---

"Well, sometimes the magic works. Sometimes, it doesn't. " - [*Old Lodge Skins*](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0016895/), in [*Little Big Man*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065988/)

Comment: Don't sweat the downvotes here on Meta.  They're used to indicate disagreement more than to indicate that a question is crap.

Comment: Hey squillman, how long have you been here? ;) good to see you.  And thanks for the pointer.  I'm currently gathering my thoughts for that upcoming "question"...should be interesting to see the reaction when it's posted (unleashed?) here.

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to MSF, now that MSF exists?

Comment: @pop: It's a question that should now be asked on MSF, yes, but this one is over a year old and the situation has changed since then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back when ServerFault was launched, [mrdenny](https://serverfault.com/users/1674/mrdenny) and [Kara Marfia](https://serverfault.com/users/1803/kara-marfia) were [appointed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/welcome-new-community-moderators/) as community moderators, a position they still hold, so there are really 3 moderators (plus [the](https://serverfault.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) [dev](https://serverfault.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) [team](https://serverfault.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) and [Joel](https://serverfault.com/users/4/joel-spolsky), but they fall under your "employees" umbrella). And given ServerFault's traffic, I think that 3 moderators are plenty.

Also, while 10k+ reputation was enough for Jeff to notice and promote splattne, it should not be construed that 10k+ in and of itself makes you elegible for consideration - lots of factors come into play. Besides, 10k+ rep users are already partially moderators because they can vote to close, delete, etc.

Comment: So there is another set of criteria that isn't mentioned.  In other words, what you read isn't what you get.  But at least I got the answer.

Comment: @Avery: Since moderators can act unilaterally, Jeff has to be very careful about who he selects. Reputation alone isn't sufficient.

Comment: Sounds like the FAQ should have a minor revision - "Moderator status at or above 10,000 reputation points is awarded based on a selection process used by SO employees", etc. etc.  Not trying to be nit-picky, but it reads "one way" and turns out "another", which makes it a bit confusing.  Just trying to help.  And thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Avery: Well the FAQ does say "moderator tools", not "moderator status", but I agree that the term is a bit overloaded here. But I'm at a loss to come up with better terms (other than "administrator", but that carries its own connotations too)

Comment: How about "Community Steward"?  "Trusted Member"?  "Community Policing"?  "Trustee"?

Comment: @Avery: You're not the first to be confused about the wording. When I hit 10k, I was expecting doves to be released and confetti. Instead, I got to access a toolset that only gives me a bit more statistics than the average user. It is in no way comparable to moderator status :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson, good to know that I'm not alone.  It's alot like "wow, while I'm browsing the user page, I can see there are users with 10k, but they're not mods...huh?  How did that happen?"

Answer (score 4):

Uh, there **are** other mods:

- https://serverfault.com/users/1674/mrdenny
- https://serverfault.com/users/1803/kara-marfia
- https://serverfault.com/users/1/jeff-atwood

You can find this on the about page of any of the sites.

ServerFault for example:

> https://serverfault.com/about

Comment: re-read the question.

Comment: @Avery: Besides @wood, they are not employees. Also, my answer was before your edit. So, re read the answer.

Comment: If you look at the top of the question before the edit, you'll see a link clearly outlined that takes you to the.... *user* page.

Comment: bah, nevermind.  Too much time invested.  I'll look at deleting the question...

Comment: You are awfully full of yourself for someone who clearly doesn't understand what the FAQ says or anything about moderation here. Try toning down the attitude. You got your question answered, my answer being one of them. Deleting the question? Why?

Comment: That seems confusing.  Let me get this straight - if the question was "so bad" that it is being voted out of existence, then explain why I should not delete it?  Isn't that the point of closing questions - to indicate that the question was somehow so horrible that it should be shunned?  Or is civility lost here too?

Comment: As far as being full of myself - well, I'm sorry you seem to think that.  It was an innocent question in search of an answer.  From my perspective, it clearly hit a nerve somewhere, which was hardly the intention.

Comment: And there lies the contradiction that is confusing to me.  I'm trying to be humble - offering to withdraw something that is being seen as a blight by others - and you then say I'm full of myself?  This is just confusing to me.  For civility's sake, I'll ask - could you clarify what you mean?  And how you arrived at those conclusions?  Obviously there's some nuance that isn't being conveyed clearly in text messages here, and I'd like to have a clear understanding of what that is.

Comment: You are too emotional. Let it be.

Answer (score 2):

Hey sweet, I'm getting paid?  Thanks for the good news!  =)

Seriously though, currently, SO's user page 1 ends at 26k, and they have only 2 community mods.  Though I think you could look at precedent to see that 10k doesn't a new moderator make, maybe this question is an indication that the wording could be more concise.  That's the point of meta, right?  If an idea gains enough traction and gets enough upvotes, it's likely to get some attention.

That said, I'm not sure the downvotes were intended to be hostile, but were possibly a vote against the idea.  It seems a little nebulous on meta, whether the downvote is used to vote against the *idea* or the *question*.  Though it's hard not to take downvotes personally.

Makes for some fiery posts, it seems.

Comment: re: fiery posts, I guess so.  Although I don't frequent SO that much, most of my time is on SF.  I'm working on a post for the near future that is very specific to things I've seen/observed on both SF and SO (and a few on SU as well), so this should be interesting...

Comment: With the current exchange rate, if I was getting paid, I could quit my day job and retire. Considering that right now it is 7 to 1 USD.

Comment: I can only imagine how beautiful the view is, too!  Sign me up if you can make that work.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I compiled a short summary of the current diamond moderator count and the links to the lists for each of them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15703/how-many-moderators-are-there-of-stackoverflow/15704#15704).

Most of the diamond moderators are chosen by voting here on Meta, for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/vote-for-super-user-moderator-poll) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/superuser-com-moderator-nomination), or in the past on the Stack Overflow [Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4428/how-a-moderator-is-chosen-in-so). That said these moderators are chosen not for their knowledge or skill particularly, but rather for their ability to manage the community and make fair judgements and resolve issues.

The 10K mods are mainly focussing on keeping the content clean, rather then managing the users. A lot of the diamond moderators you will find actually don't have very high reputation counts, with the few exceptions.

The major differences of the tools provided to moderators is listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/moderator-abilities). Also diamond moderators have final say powers, if we close or delete it is immediate, no 5 user waiting period as is the case with 10K moderators. Also diamond moderators can view moderator tags and flags.

Lastly we get the Flame-throwers. We can ban, destroy and even delete user accounts.

Comment: Interesting.  And thanks for the info! (+1)  Now where did I put that full-body fire suit? ;)