# How are moderators chosen?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges)
>   [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)

I want to know how moderator make decision on just flagging. There might be some misunderstanding or moderator may took decision which is not correct.

People are getting afraid of room owner that they might kick off them from the room or flag the message to the moderator. How moderator gets elected? Or they do have salary for do the job of moderator.

If person wants to become a moderator, How will he/she be moderator. Or there might be not correct  decision while taking decision will moderator be punished just general question dont be personal request to all moderators.

Comment: Re room owner - are you talking about chat, or the site?

Comment: I think we have a very decent staff of moderators who are [elected by the community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4428/how-a-moderator-is-chosen-in-so)

Comment: Instead of making blanket statements, could you bring forth the actual issues (but not necessarily naming names) you are experiencing.

Comment: m talking about whole procedure...like general public trying impress room owners and room owners trying to impress moderators....i dont why all is this happening?

Comment: i m not blaiming all moderators.....i had been mention in my question don take it personel...its just a general question

Comment: some background: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/759145#759145

Comment: What room owners are you referring to where exactly?

Comment: as @sathya mention the link....like with flagging how moderator can take a decision m talking about that!!!!

Comment: i know why people are downvoting my question because i put question on moderator which i think some people get angry with my question

Comment: @Cody Gray, the people who created the room.

Comment: Also, balpha [is a developer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/) working for SE. He's not a community-elected moderator.

Comment: i want to know is chatting in hindi is an offense.....

Comment: @ManjotSingh, it wasn't chatting in hindi that was the problem, it was what was said (implied) and what was said in english as well.

Comment: i told @tombull89..i am talking in general...may user dont have better command on english n having japanese or russian or hindi...may feel better in chatting in other language....so is there any offense in it..

Comment: if two user feel confortable in chatting in hindi then why dont they chat in hindi in the chat rooms

Comment: I'm inclined to argue that since the site is in English, all chat should be conducted in English. But since I don't participate in chat, I can't say whether or not that's an official policy. But either way, you're missing the point. The problem here was clearly not chatting in another language, it was the *content* of what was said.

Comment: @code gray...i mention that moderator may took decision which might not correct...as @sathya mention the link...i was chatting in hindi people start flagging my messages and room onwer kick me out from the room....till then okay...then i created a gallery room where people can chat in any language there i dint invite anyone to flag my messages....people came in the room start flagging my messages....this is not fair that if people are playing politics n making a group and start flagging the messages and moderator should take decision while seeing all things....

Comment: when i ask question on meta.stackoverflow.com again @sathya start disscussing about me in public rooms....literally i feel powerless.....

Comment: You seem to be confusing a lot of different things. The room owner isn't the same person as the moderator. The room owner obviously has the right to choose who to allow to chat in his/her room. If you want to chat anyway, create a room of your own. Moderators are different. I think balpha provided a very good explanation of why you were banned from chat. It had nothing to do with the language and everything to do with the *content* of the communication. The chat rooms are less formal than the website itself, but you're still expected to conduct yourself maturely and respectfully.

Comment: And Sathya is not discussing about you in public. He's answering a question that you asked. Not sure what else you expected here... This is a Q&A site for discussing and solving problems.

Comment: @Cody Gray as u say create ur own room...i created my own room,http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/729/android...i know why balpha banned me from the chat room because people flag my messages..i mention in question how moderator can took a decision by just flagged messages  and i know the difference between moderator and room owner....

Comment: @Cody Gray u can check the transcript of http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access...he is continously disscussing with Mokubai and tombull89 publically...

Comment: Creating your own room solves the problem of the room owner asking you to leave. It doesn't solve the problem of being banned. Those are the two things you're confusing. No one has *ever* said anything about the reason you were banned being because of flags. I don't know where you got the idea it was related to flags, but the flaggers *certainly* didn't make the decision to ban you. The reason you were banned seems pretty clear to me. And like I just told your [colleague in crime](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92488/), if you still don't understand, maybe you don't belong there.

Comment: @Cody Gray if u will take look on the transcript of http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/729/android raynos is saying "@ManjotSingh you realize people keep flagging your posts right?
There are 6 flags" so that means moderators are considering flags only...

Comment: And as far as Sathya talking about you, well, he's not talking about *you*, he's talking about your *behavior*. Which you did in a public forum for everyone in the world to see. There's nothing off-limits about what he's saying. He isn't saying bad things about you personally, he's explaining what took place to other users. You don't have any right to complain when your rear end in public and people talk about it later...

Comment: **No, moderators do not consider flags only.** Flags might be how people bring things to their attention because they simply can't be everywhere at once. But the moderators are still people (we don't use robot mods yet), and they still make decisions for themselves. Clearly the one involved here thought your behavior was egregious enough to justify a ban. If you'd like to discuss that more with him, you should follow [these already-linked instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges).

Comment: @Cody Gray after debating sometime with Raynos balpha came banned me u can check the transcript of http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/729/android that means they are considering flags onlu

Comment: @Cody Gray after yesterday night when all is happened till then okay..i started room on stackexchange there also we are chatting in hindi n then @Sathya came suspend me from the SO blocked the room....now i want to ask @Sathya what was my fault at that time...why he suspend me from the stackexchange because i am debating with him....did i disrespect him u can ask him only why did he close the room in stackexchange i can wait for the 30 for stackoverflow.....

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: @ManjotSingh -> "raynos is saying.." -> That's an indication to you that you're doing something *wrong*. TBH this comment thread is getting extended for no reason. Balpha told you, CodyGray has been patient with you, I've told you and yet **you're** not willing to **understand** the reasons for your suspension. Flags are there to highlight bad behaviour - Moderators cannot keep a watch on every single message posted.

Comment: @Sathya i am not saying Moderator keep watch on every messages but they should not take decision only on flags atleast they should ask the user....is Balpha ask me anything about the issue.... why did you suspended me from stackexchange....why were you disscussing with people publically....

Comment: Also, @ManjotSingh **you were suspended from chat.stackexchange for the very same reason you were suspended by Balpha - you behaviour was despicable**, and you were [bragging about having](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1029657#1029657) found a loophole(!) about your ban on chat.so. Also, it didn't help that you pretty much told me I had no rights to be in Android room because [I am not an Android dev](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/495). Again, think about your behaviour and come back.

Comment: look @Cody Gray again i am feeling powerless....@Sathya took a decision letting me out from the chat room or suspended from the Stackexchange because he is Moderator and having powers of letting anyone out....till 30 days i can not chat in stackoverflow i can wait for a month.... then why did @Sathya kicked me out from the room i know why because he is moderator and using his power....but i want to know did i disrespect any one on the stackexchange

Comment: Manjot, you were suspended from chat for *appaling* conduct.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with @Sathya's decision. Especially looking at the links he provided in his last comment. I think you'll be hard-pressed to find another user on this site (much less a moderator) who doesn't agree with the ban and thinks you have a real case here. It's one thing to be rude, inappropriate, and disrespectful. It's quite another to be so ignorant that you don't even realize there's anything *wrong* with being rude, inappropriate, and disrespectful.

Comment: @tombull89 did i appaling conduct on stackexchange with anyone....@Cody Gray i agree with u that i did things which was not correct on stackoverflow and i am ready to take punishment to be ban till 30 days from stackoverflow but i dint anything wrong on stackexchange so i request @Sathya please dont suspend me from the stackexchange i am requesting you because you are moderator....

Comment: @ManjotSingh: I would suggest you to just drop it and live with the consequences of appealing conduct, being suspended from the chat is not the worst thing in the world. As far as I understand you are still free to be on Stack Exchange itself as long as you don't continue your behavior here, you shouldn't be [begging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging) for something that you still have as it really won't make a *positive* change when it becomes necessary...

Comment: @TomWij still i dont have write access on Stack Exchange because my account is suspended....

Comment: @ManjotSingh, you are not (currently) banned from any of the Stack Exchange  sites (StackOveflow, SuperUser, ServerFult, etc), only the chat rooms.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How moderator gets elected

Stack Exchange conducts [elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-election) at varied intervals.

> they do have salary for do the job of moderator

No, it is voluntary.

> If person wants to become a moderator,How will he/she be moderator

Win the elections!

> moderator may took decision which is not correct

Ask a question about this.

Comment: "Win the elections!" Spoken like a true winner. ;-)

Comment: @cody Gray tell me the procedure definitely i will try for the same...

Comment: Are these really the types of interesting things that I miss by not participating in chat? I'm honestly not sure if that makes me more or less inclined to join in the fun.

Comment: @CodyGray fortunately, these are rare.

Comment: I'll second that. This is _very_ rare - AFIAK this is the first incident on this scale.

Comment: It got real ugly! Flags were flying all over the place! Possibly signs of the Rapture.