# What are the different types of reasons for banning a particular user?

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

I want to know the reasons why I was banned from Stack Overflow. Actually, I was banned from 23/5/2011 without any warning.

I do not understand the reasons why I was banned from the Stack Overflow chat rooms. I am not suspended from Stack Overflow. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: None of your accounts is suspended. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: do you mean banned from Stack Overflow or suspeneded from chat? There is a difference.

Comment: @Pekka'sothertrollingaccount he's been suspended from chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/759145#759145

Comment: I am banned for 1 month for chat room in Stack overflow

Comment: can i know why i here is negative voting ? i want to know only the reason thats all

Comment: normally, downvotes on meta mean disagreement. In this case, however, it is probably your attitude.

Comment: @tombull89: If by "attitude", you mean the sheer incredulity that these people have for *why* they were banned. As I mentioned in a comment to his compatriot, it's one thing to be rude and disrespectful. It's quite another to be completely ignorant as to what things are rude and disrespectful, and be dumbfounded that people would actually care.

Comment: @Dharmendra: Questions like these are considered "rant" as they are not useful nor clear to the majority of users that are on this site, they feel that it doesn't change a thing and shouldn't really belong here. I would have suggested you to use the "Contact us" link at the bottom instead for elaboration, but it seems you have already gotten your answer so just don't mind. I've up-voted your question because it's fine to ask something when you don't understand or see why you are suspended...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You were **not** banned or even temporarily suspended from Stack Overflow, or from any of the other Stack Exchange sites. If you had been, your profile would indicate such with a red banner at the top, and you would have received a notification email.

However, you *were* suspended from chat for 30 days by [balpha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) (one of the f[riendly Stack Exchange developers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/), who also help to moderate the site, in addition to the community-elected moderators). This suspension was in response to your conduct in [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/759145#759145), where you went by the nickname "Dr.Jackal". He left you the following explanatory message:

> @DrJackal @ManjotSingh @Wanted I've had enough. I'm suspending you from chat for 30 days. Those messages I understand are enough; I don't even want to know what the other ones mean. If you don't know how to behave among human beings, you're not welcome here. You're free to come back after a month if you're ready to show you can behave.

This ban is completely consistent with the minimum expectations established in the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq), to which you agreed when you began chatting in the rooms:

> Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members.
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> #### Do I have to be nice?
>
> Yes. We expect community members to treat each other with respect … even when they don't deserve it.
>
> This site is collectively moderated by the community through participatory flagging. If your chat messages are repeatedly being flagged by your peers you might find yourself muted, banned, or – in extreme cases – your Stack Overflow reputation may be negatively affected.
>
> If you see an inappropriate, spam, or offensive chat message, please use the hover menu at the far right of each chat message to flag it. This will draw it to the attention of the community moderators.

Comment: can i know what are the reasons for banned me by "balpha" ?

Comment: @Dharmendra: balpha is the nickname of a particular user here on this site. I've linked to his profile in my answer. His real name is Benjamin Dumke, and he's one of the site moderators and developers. The *reason* you were banned is because you failed to meet the minimum expectation of behaving respectfully and maturely in our chat rooms. They may be less formal than the site proper, but there are still some minimum standards for conduct. If you don't even understand why what you did is unacceptable, then perhaps you shouldn't *ever* be allowed to use the chat rooms...

Comment: please show me any communication which you can say that is "minimum standards"

Comment: @Dharmendra: Seriously? You really don't think that maintaining a modicum of decency, acting like a mature human being, and conducting yourself respectfully towards others is a **minimum standard** of behavior on the Internet? Because I think it is. And if you're not prepared to accept that, perhaps we should consider broadening and/or extending the current ban.

Comment: From the Chat FAQ ... `Do have fun, but please keep it professional and always be respectful of your fellow community members.`

Comment: And also `We expect community members to treat each other with respect … even when they don't deserve it.`  [Chat FAQ](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: ok so you mean i have not give respect to some one.ok then my banned is valid for me i am accepting this banned but i want to know what is the sentense that i have told someone that is consider as a minimum standard

Comment: Just for a minute, close your eyes and imagine what it would be like if we didn't need to state the obvious things as "rules" and we could just expect people to act like civilized mature human beings. And then snap back to reality where we *do* explicitly state these things, and *still* people don't understand why they have to follow them or why there are consequences for choosing *not* to follow them.

Comment: These comments look like a 419 scam

Answer (score 2):

Your account will not be suspended unless you have violated one of the site's rules.

If you can follow the rules, you can participate on the site and be rewarded with knowledge.