# Should user talk at chat room in other language than english?

Tags: discussion, chat

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are the different types of reasons for banning a particular user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92488/what-are-the-different-types-of-reasons-for-banning-a-particular-user)
>   [How are moderators chosen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92486/how-are-moderators-chosen)

If one user want to explain a thing to other user(who understands) in his first language, is he doing anything wrong?

Also can user create a language specific chat room for his country mates?

What is wrong if users talk in other language in separate room? (Only technical discussion and with discipline)

Comment: This question is related to these questions [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92488/what-are-the-different-types-of-reasons-for-banning-a-particular-user/92491#comment-231210) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92486/how-are-moderators-chosen)

Comment: All three questions are directly related to the three of you being banned from Chat, therefore they are related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is nobody else in the room at the moment, and you want to explain things, I suppose it is okay. However, if two people began speaking in a different language in front of me (in real life) and they knew I didn't speak it, that would be rude. Considering that SE is a group of English speaking sites, your use "constitutes knowledge" (I am not a lawyer, nor representing SE, just stating my perception of the rules.)

The other thing to consider is the transcript. People who read it will likely not understand it.

Additionally, since SE is an English language website, do not create rooms for other languages. (Although, I have spotted a room in Russian...)

For better of for worse, language barriers tend to frustrate not only those asking questions, but also native English speakers who try to answer the questions. I suggest sticking with English here.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the site's Moderators are also going to find it much harder to make informed rulings if people start having discussions in languages the moderators don't understand.

Comment: Very valid point.

Answer (score 8):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92488/what-are-the-different-types-of-reasons-for-banning-a-particular-user/) and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92486/how-are-moderators-chosen), because they're the same basic question with strawman excuses.

#### Q: Why were we banned for speaking Hindi?

#### Q: Why were we banned for being flagged?

**A**: No one was banned for speaking Hindi, and no one was banned for being flagged. Actually, no one was even banned at all.

Y'all were *suspended* (note: *not* "banned") for 30 days for [the reasons given here by balpha](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/759145#759145):

> I've had enough. I'm suspending you from chat for 30 days. Those messages I understand are enough; I don't even want to know what the other ones mean. If you don't know how to behave among human beings, you're not welcome here. You're free to come back after a month if you're ready to show you can behave.

---

@Wanted, @Dharmendra (aka @Dr.Jackal<sup>*</sup>), and @ManjotSingh:

Please… take some time and *think* about why you were suspended. Don't think up excuses as to why you might have been suspended, but about why you were saying offensive things, and what you'll do differently next time.

---

<sup>* Using both accounts in a single MSO post? That's not terribly bright…</sup>

Comment: What with all the kurfuffle, duplicate posts and so-on, there's still one thing that *isn't* clear to me, and that I think needs to be confirmed **explicitly**: *Are you saying that it **is** ok to have dedicated foreign-language chat rooms?* (as long as they follow the house rules, etc. etc)

Comment: Yeah, there is a valid question in here, even though it was created as a straw-man.

Comment: @Benj, @Pekka - That's definitely an interesting question (and I don't know if there's a resolved answer for it), but this is a lousy case to use to start that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I think if all the users of the rooms are of same region and if all have no problem with language then you can communicate with each other with your language because nobody of your room have objection with your language

If some people have problem with English for communication and if they want to explain their question and answer in there language then i think it is good

but i think for that all users of that room have to be agree with your language

and also if you are communicating with each other in other language then must keep it in your mind that you must have to behave like a professional

You can not use a low level content in your Room because some times it can be difficult for moderator to find low level content.

Comment: yes there can be a problem but thare is your responsibility to be a professional in your room and if moderator get flag and if he/she can not detemind then he/she can give you panelty