# Explicit read access in chat?

Tags: support, chat

Under a chat room's access panel you can do things like set owners, one of the things is add read access.

> **Explicit read access add a user**
>
> Even when this room is private, these users will be able to read the conversations in this room.

What I don't understand is how to get a private room, I thought all rooms were always readable, as there seems to be no private option.

Answer (score 5):

Private rooms are a moderator-only tool reserved for moderation purposes. So there are essentially no private rooms except a few used by moderators and there is no way for a normal user to make a room private.

Comment: Ah, is the rational behind that on meta somewhere?

Comment: @Incognito: The rationale is pretty simple, we have to have some way to moderate the chat rooms. A while back, we had [an epidemic of problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92488/what-are-the-different-types-of-reasons-for-banning-a-particular-user) regarding bad behavior in the chat rooms. Those users wanted to create private rooms where "anything goes", but no one else in the community felt that was a good idea. I don't think there's any specific documentation of this on Meta beyond the regular site FAQ, which explains the theory behind community moderation and edit ability.